# SO mobile site doesn't highlight favourite tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

SO mobile site doesn't highlight favourite tags the same way desktop site does.

When looking at the main page http://stackoverflow.com, ordered by "interesting", the desktop site highlights question tagged with my favourite tags:

> [image]

and the mobile version does not:

> [image]

The images were taken on the same computer with the same browser.

The mobile version does highlight favourite tags in other views (i.e. under https://stackoverflow.com/questions).

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232288/favourite-tag-highlighting-gone-on-mobile-site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks. A [recent bugfix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128047/mobile-site-highlighting-someone-elses-favourite-tags) worked correctly on most question lists, but not on the homepage.